# Loading OECD data into pandas with pandaSDMX

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to load industrial production data (with revisions history) from the OECD. The data can be found at http://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=MEI_ARCHIVE#.

I would like to load the data into a pandas environment in Python using pandaSDMX (https://pandasdmx.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

```
from pandasdmx import Request
oecd = Request('OECD')
cat_response = oecd.categoryscheme()
```

I am getting the following error, suggesting that the code is not able to find the url required.

```
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://stats.oecd.org/SDMX-JSON/categoryscheme?references=parentsandsiblings
```

Is there a way to work around this? Have others experienced similar problems with OECD data and pandaSDMX?

Answer (score 1):

The OECD's API used by pandaSDMX Supports requests for datasets only, hence no categoryscheme, no datastructure, no dataflow. You have to figure out the dataflow ID and desired Dimension values yourself through the web Interface and issue the data request.